# button size in chrome

Tags: css, button

I am trying to set the size of a button in Chrome as very small ones, 4x4, or 5x5 px, but I´m getting some really weird results. My code is:

```
<input type="button" style="height: 4px; width: 4px; background-color: #aabbfe"; onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='#aabbfe'";/>
```

Although height and width are the same, the result is a horizontal rectangular button.

The only way I could get a square proportion (which is what I want) was setting height:14px by width: 5px, which does not make sense, and also, I simply can´t get the buttons to become smaller in Chrome.

Anyone could show me where did I go stupid? I´m sure I must be overlooking something very basic, but I just can´t find it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the padding from the button.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzuAh/1/)

```
input {
    padding:0;
}
```

This is caused by the following style applied in the Chrome user agent stylesheet.

```
input[type="button"], 
input[type="submit"], 
input[type="reset"], 
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, 
button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT, JSFiddle, you´re the best! So #$%#$¨% Chrome applies padding by default and DOESN´T WARN US...nice.

Comment: Uh...I´m a little confused here...looking at the reply I can´t tell for sure, I´m new here, this answer came from JSFiddle or Tyriar? Well, whoever, thanks a lot again, it worked just fine!

Comment: Tyriar made the jsfiddle and got the rules from chrome :)

Comment: Thank you @DanielImms, I had the same issue (with circular buttons not square) in Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to remove the margin and padding as well as the border if they are not required. These may all have an effect on the dimensions of an element.